# Send a message to multiple recipients in whatsapp business cloud api

Tags: api, whatsapp

Is there a way to send a message to multiple recipients in one post request?
The same way I send emails separated with a semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option in WhatsApp Business Cloud API to send messages to multiple phone numbers at one go, you have to do that one by one or through the loop.

Comment: thanks, can you please give info on the rate limit applied if using a loop?

Comment: As per the [latest update](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-platform/changelog#cloud-api---september-7--2022), *Cloud API now supports up to 250 messages per second of combined sending and receiving of text and media messages*.